# Instant time from week of year

Tags: java, time, java-time

I need to get `Instant` time from week number of year. Now I'm using old `Calendar` API to calculate time:

```
int week = 1; // week of year
final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // reset calendar
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Year.now().getValue());
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
final Instant start = cal.getTime().toInstant();
final Instant end = start.plus(Period.ofWeeks(1));
```

Is it possible to get `Instant` from week of year using new Java time API (`java.time` package)?

Comment: Using the new Date API take rid of Calendar. You might possibly acheive this without calendar

Comment: What is `start`?

Comment: @BrunoDM sorry, I renamed `instant` to `start`

Comment: Tks @Kirill. I made a answer for you

Comment: How are your week numbers? `GregorianCalendar` would use the week numbering of the default locale of the JVM, is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());

    int week = 1; // week of year

    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .with(wf.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), week)
            .with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1);
    Instant startInstant = startDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusWeeks(1);
    Instant endInstant = endDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

    System.out.println("" + startInstant + " - " + endInstant);
```

My locale uses ISO week numbers. The output here was:

> 2019-12-29T00:00:00Z - 2020-01-05T00:00:00Z

If you want ISO weeks independently of the locale, set `wf` to `WeekFields.ISO`. If you want some other week numbering scheme, set `wf` accordingly.

In case any other readers were wondering, Kirill is defining the end of the week as the first moment of the following week. This is recommended. It’s known as using *half-open intervals* for time intervals.

I also agree with the question that one should clearly prefer using java.time for this task rather than `Calendar`. `Calendar` is poorly designed and long outdated, and I believe that the code using java.time is clearer to read.

Furthermore, the code in the question using `Calendar` doesn’t set the day to the first day of the week, so will not give you that day. And while I haven’t tested, I suspect that the code will sometimes produce unexpected results around New Year.

My code using `WeekFields` from java.time will stay within the current *week-based year*, which is not the same as the calendar year. For example, if I had run it on December 30, 2019, it would still have given med week 1 of 2020 because we were already in that week.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the week using the following methods:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0);
System.out.println(localDateTime); //2020-01-01T00:00
localDateTime = localDateTime.with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2);
System.out.println(localDateTime); //2020-01-08T00:00
localDateTime = localDateTime.plusWeeks(10);
System.out.println(localDateTime); //2020-03-18T00:00
```

and to parse it to Instant depends on what class from the API you are using:

```
LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+04:00"));
ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant();
```

The `LocalDateTime` doest not have a Zone, so you must a provide a `ZoneOffset` to parse it to a Instant.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the month you can use this lambda expression:

```
LocalDate.now().with(temporal
                -> temporal.with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1l)
        );
```

Now get instant is easy:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().with(temporal
                -> temporal.with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1l)
        );
Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

If you don't want cto change time, then you can use this instead of last line:

```
Instant instant = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.now()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```